# Assert.AreEqual method usage in checking DataTable types

Tags: c#, assert

I have gone through threads given but wasn't able to find an implementation for pass case in c# (msdn website has no datatable/generic collection assert usage either)..

code at client not with us (only the 2 datatables are returned to us)

```
datarow dr1 = datatable1.newrow();
dr1[0] = 345;

datarow dr2 = datatable1.newrow()
dr2[0] = 345;

datatable1.rows.add(dr1); //(1)
datatable2.rows.add(dr2); //(2)
```

code at our end

```
Assert.AreEqual(dt1,dt2); //fails!!How to pass this case??
```

Comment: And what exactly does it fail as? It should say the message, whether it is difference in values or it is trying to compare references.

Comment: Because both are different references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of the AreEqual method is using [`Assert.AreEqual(Object expected, Object actual)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx) . This means that it will be using `Object.Equals()` for the comparison.

Run this code and see what the value is:

```
bool areEqual = dr1.Equals(dr2);
```

This will return false, because they are not the same reference. Look at the documentation for `Object.Equals`:

> If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method. Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to the same object.

You need to find a more appropriate way to compare your data. You can use a `DataRowComparer` to compare the values instead. You can also loop through each of your rows and compare the values yourself. See [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-compare-rows) for an example.

Comment: I know this is a very old question. But thanks. This was what proved as a solution back then.

Answer (score 4):

`Assert.AreEqual` is going to use the `Equals` method on the type.  `DataTable` does not override this method, so this is a reference check.  This means that `dt1` is not equal to `dt2`.

You could use `CollectionAssert`, but this will do a comparison on the members.  Again, `DataRow` does not override `Equals`, so it will do a reference check.

You will need to write custom comparison logic, then do something like `Assert.IsTrue(DataTableComparer.AreEqual(dt1, dt2));`

Comment: Do you mean [`DataRowComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907955.aspx)?

Comment: Nope, that was a class name I made up on the spot for purposes of this example.  I didn't even know `DataRowComparer` existed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while developing my own CSV parsing library. I have written an assertion that throws exceptions in a way that can be used
in unit tests.

```
public static class AssertDataTable {

    public static void AreEqual(DataTable expected, DataTable actual) {
        //If both tables are null we consider them equal.
        if ((expected == null) && (actual == null)) {
            return;
        } else if ((expected != null) && (actual != null)) {
            //Check that the column count is the same
            if ((expected.Columns.Count == actual.Columns.Count)) {
                //Check that the column types are the same
                for (int i = 0; i < expected.Columns.Count; i++) {
                    if (expected.Columns[i].DataType != actual.Columns[i].DataType) {
                        throw new Exception($"The type of of columns is not the same in both tables! Expected:{expected.Columns[i].DataType} Actual:{actual.Columns[i].DataType} for index {i}");
                    }
                }
                //Check that the headers are the same
                for (int i = 0; i < expected.Columns.Count; i++) {
                    if (expected.Columns[i].ColumnName != actual.Columns[i].ColumnName) {
                        throw new Exception($"Column names do not match! Expected:{expected.Columns[i].ColumnName} Actual:{actual.Columns[i].ColumnName} for index {i}");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Tables do not have the same number of columns");
            }

            //Up to this point we have verified the columns. Now we are going th verify the rows
            //Just verify the values. Types have already been verified through the column checks.
            if (expected.Rows.Count == actual.Rows.Count) {
                for (int i = 0; i < expected.Columns.Count; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < expected.Rows.Count; j++) {
                        if (!expected.Rows[j][i].Equals(actual.Rows[j][i])) {
                            throw new Exception($"Cells are not equal! In Row {j} and Column {i} Expected {expected.Rows[j][i]} Actual {actual.Rows[j][i]}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                return;
            } else {
                throw new Exception($"Rows count is not equal! Expected{expected.Rows.Count} Actual {actual.Rows.Count}");
            }
        } else {
            //Give more information to the user.
            if (expected == null) {
                throw new Exception("Expected table is null! But Actual table is not.");
            }

            if (actual == null) {
                throw new Exception("Actual table is null! But expected table is not.");
            }
        }
    } //End of Compare Data Datatables
} //End of class
```

I have also taken account the suggetions made by [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) and [gunr2171](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043380/gunr2171).
The code can also be found on the relevant [Github Repo](https://github.com/arkaragian/AlphaCSV/blob/develop/TestAlphaCSV/AssertDataTable.cs)

This way I can use this method in a unit test as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SingleTest() {
    //Arrange
    DataTable expected = new DataTable();
    //Build my table here
    
    //Act
    DataTable actual = CustomMethodToTest();

    //Assert
    AssertDataTable.AreEqual(expected, actual); 
}
```

I post this in the hopes that this post may help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

AreEqual compares by reference unless object overrides the "Equals" method

Try the below, pasted from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23703a85-20c7-4759-806a-fabf4e9f5be6/how-to-compare-two-datatables

```
Assert.IsTrue(ComareDataTables(DTable1,DTable2));

private bool CompareDataTables(DataTable DT1, DataTable DT2)
    {
        if ((DT1 == null) && (DT2 == null))
            return true;
        else if ((DT1 != null) && (DT2 != null))
        {
            if (DT1.Rows.Count == DT2.Rows.Count)
            {
                if (DT1.Columns.Count == DT2.Columns.Count)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < DT1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; j<DT1.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (DT1.Rows[i][j].ToString() != DT2.Rows[i][j].ToString())
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need an `else` if you `return` in the `if`.  With that in mind, I'd recommend inverting your if conditions so you aren't so deeply nested.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be comparing the string values of the items.  I'd first compare the types of the columns, to veryify that they are the same, and if they are, use `object.Equals` to compare the individual cells.  That will both handle null values, be faster, and handle the possible case of two different objects having the same string representation (which is not actually that absurd of a concept).